# Why is my DIV not centered?

Tags: html, css

Why the div below not centered?

```
<div align="center" style="width: 980px; height: 202px; top: 0px; position: absolute;">
<div style="width: 235px; position: relative; z-index: 1;"><a href="index.php"><img border="0" src="images/logo.png" alt="" /></a></div>
</div>
```

I tried a lot of different css styles, but for some reason this div isn't centered on the page.

Comment: Why are you using `top: 0px; position: absolute;`? Just to make the `div` touch the top of the page?

Comment: You might also want to change `align="center"` to `text-align="center"`. I have never heard of `align` before.

Answer (score 3):

`margin: auto` will center a fixed-width block element:

```
<div style="width: 980px; height: 202px; margin: auto">
    <div style="width: 235px">
        <a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png" style="border: none;"/></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't think it will work on an absolutely positioned element, but I doubt that in your example it needs to be positioned in that way.

Comment: if you introduce modal windows with z-index values this method will not work

Answer (score 1):

```
#wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:50%;
    width:800px;
    margin:0px auto 0px -400px;
}
```

if you want the page centered ... 
what makes this work is that you set a negative value to the left margin that is equal to 1/2 the div width

Answer (score 0):

Because you're setting it to:

```
position: absolute; top:0px;
```

This will make it appear at the top left of it's parent positioned-div.

Comment: I need a floating center div... there is another way to do that without position absolute?

Comment: (This was my answer to his actual question "why isn't it being centered" - I edited the post title to ask what I think he meant, which is "how do I center a div")

Comment: @John - yes - position absolute will not center your div - ever.  (Unless you're talking about a specific monitor size only.)  Try using margin: auto (like mentioned above) or even fall back to the good ole' <center> tag (not recommended, but - if you don't understand CSS it might be worth doing)